# From pandas dataframe to multidimensional numpy array for compatibility with tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns contains lists:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
(
   pd.DataFrame({
      "x": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
   )}
   .assign(x = lambda data: data.x.apply(np.array))  # convert lists into numpy arrays
   .to_numpy()
   .shape  # returns (3, 1) when I was hoping for a (3,1,2)
)
```

I would like to pass this data into tensorflow as a 3D array, but first I need to be able to get the right shape out of it.

Many thanks!

Comment: @JvdV, I'm not a 100% sure, but I thought it should be (3,1,2): 3 rows, 1 column with 2 dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve it like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
npArr = np.array(pd.DataFrame({"x": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
                               "y": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]}).values.tolist())
print(npArr.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a few follow up questions: (1) I thought that the first dimension should correspond to rows, any ideas on why the first dimension is 1 (column)? E.g. if I do `pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3]}).to_numpy().shape` it returns `(3,1)` as expected

Comment: And one more question: while the proposed solution makes sense, I feel like it's not quite complete for my use-case (even though it actually answers the original question): you see, I have 1000s of multidimensional variables like `x` and  I would like to keep them all in one dataset, so would you be able to expand you answer to cover a case where the output table covers multiple columns, so instead of (1,3,2), say (2,3,2)?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: it's based of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52442684/9758194) answer by @jezrael. I credited, so please also give credit where credit is due =)

Comment: @IVR, you are welcome. Please see above comment which direct to another post that has been of great help. Also, let's clean up the comments below question/answer.